# 3.5 mm wired headset with good mic

Tags: headset

I am looking for a headset for phone calls with the following features:

- Good microphone
- Good audio quality
- Good build quality
- 3.5 mm connector
- I want to hear my own voice as I would in normal speaking (if I hear my voice damped, I have the tendency to speak louder which feels uncomfortable)
- Comfortable fit for smaller persons
- No or only slight blocking of sourrounding noise
- No cable noise if you tip on the cable

I am not sure if it would be a good idea to go with a mono headset.

Based on reviews from the web the following devices may be a reasonable choice: [Yealink UH 36](https://www.yealink.com/en/product-detail/microsoft-teams-headset-uh36) or [UH 34](https://www.yealink.com/en/product-detail/microsoft-teams-headset-uh34), Jabra [Evolve 30](https://www.jabra.com/business/office-headsets/jabra-evolve/jabra-evolve-30##5399-829-309) or [Evolve 40](https://www.jabra.com/accessories/jabra-evolve40-replacement-headset). However with the jabra I have read there is cable noise. What do you think?

Comment: Honestly getting a headphone that sounds like you would in normal speaking is going to be **highly** subjective. I would instead suggest purchasing one of these headsets that has a decent frequency response curve, download some free audio tuning software like [FxSound](https://www.fxsound.com/download) and tweaking the sound to your idea of "organic".